# write get.ElementByClass() from nested div to file

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm working on a chatbot where users can talk to the chatbot and
I would like to have the conversation logged into a text file. I was thinking grabbing the `<div class="msg-text">`, which represent the conversation the `document.getElementByClass("msg-text")[0].innerText;` which is the chatbot's response and the `document.getElementByClass("msg-text")[1].innerText;` which is the user's response and have it to be read into a file.
The chatbot response in even numbers (0,2,4,6,8, etc.) and the odd number (1,3,5,7,9, etc.) is the user's response.

Is there a more efficient way to grab the elements and have them written to a file? At this moment I get nothing in my file.

```js
// This function finds odd/even and write to file
function findTheOddOnes_ToFile() {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
        thefile = fso.CreateTextFile("/Desktop/even.txt", True);
 
  // find odd/even numbers in element
    for (var i=0;i => document.getElementsByClassName("msg-text").length;i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0) {
        //If even add the chatbots respons to file. Chatbot respons are even numbes (0,2,4,6,etc)
        //write to file 
      thefile.writeline("chatbot: " + document.getElementsByClassName("msg-text")[i].textContent + "<br>");
      }
        else{
         //if Odd write to file as users respons (1,3,5,7,etc)
        //write to file 
      thefile.writeline("You: : " + document.getElementsByClassName("msg-text")[i].textContent);
       }
      }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <section class="msger">
    <header class="msger-header">
      <div class="msger-header-title">
        <i class="fas fa-bug"></i> SE Chatbot <i class="fas fa-bug"></i>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main class="msger-chat">
      <div class="msg left-msg">
        <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/327/327779.svg)"></div>

        <div class="msg-bubble">
          <div class="msg-info">
            <div class="msg-info-name">SEBot_real</div>
            <div class="msg-info-time">12:45</div>
          </div>

          <div class="msg-text">
            Hi, welcome to SE-Bot! Go ahead and send me a message. 
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, don't call document.getElementsByClassName() multiple times.  Also, what happens if the user types in something twice before the chatbot responds?

I would recommend you add a `msg-bubble-user` and `msg-bubble-bot` to your `.msg-bubble` element.  Then loop through them, recording the transcript according to the class name, not the position:

```js
document.querySelector(".msg-bubble").forEach(el=>{
    const speaker = el.matches(".msg-bubble-user") ? "You" : "Chatbot";
    const content = el.querySelector(".msg-text").textContent;
    thefile.writeline(`${speaker}: ${content}<br />`);
});
```

*^untested*

If your file is empty, add a `console.log()` call to see if you're getting the text you're expecting.

Comment: At this moment, if a user types too fast the chatbot freezes and starts spamming the user to try to catch up. I'm thinking of making the chatbot only answer the last typed response from the user.

Comment: Or maybe disable the input field once the user has submitted - re-enable when the chatbot responds.